# userModel.lastUser содержит пустую строку

Tags: qt, qml, kde

Создаю собственную тему *SDDM*. В ходе разработки заметил, что `userModel.lastUser` содержит пустую строку в тестовом режиме. Проверил на других темах офоромления *SDDM* - то же самое. В обычном  режиме всё ок. Как можно исправить это?

Делал всё в соответствии с официальной документацией: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/wiki/Theming

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста свой исходный код

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичный вопрос был задан в английской версии stackoverflow, и имеет принятый [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209271/usermodel-lastuser-contains-empty-string)